# ffmpeg put multiple pictures into different frames

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, pyffmpeg

my array in Python looks like this `[['0.3251', '6.5712', '12.8174', '13.3979', '13.9784', '14.5357', '14.9537', '15.1394', '15.5109', '16.3236', '16.5094', '16.6951', '17.2524', '17.6704', '18.0419']]` and I need to put put one image on that exact same second like in that array with ffmpeg. How can I do that?
For an example I want a video with a song
on first `0.3251s of the video i want to put img1` second `6.5712s of the video i want to put img2` and so on.

Comment: You need to figure out how to run FFmpeg first to accomplish your goal, then code it in Python to automate. My first inclination is to have 1 input audio stream and N input image streams and combine the video streams with a filtergraph. When you have actual python code, update your question to explain your effort to get a better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not know much about Python but here is an example of a Windows batch file how you can create a video with images and sound by using FFmpeg.

This example uses `mp3` file with sound, three `jpg` files with images and two of your starting points: `0.3251` and `6.5712`. First image will be displayed since start of the output video to `0.3251`, second image will be displayed from `0.3251` to `6.5712`, third image will be displayed from `6.5712` to the end of the sound. You can easily add more input images and starting points by following the same pattern (I included one example at the end of this post).

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp3 -loop 1 -i input1.jpg -loop 1 -i input2.jpg -loop 1 -i input3.jpg -filter_complex ^
 ^"[1:v]trim=duration=0.3251[a]; ^
   [2:v]trim=start=0.3251:end=6.5712,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; ^
   [a][b]concat[c]; ^
   [3:v]trim=start=6.5712,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; ^
   [c][d]concat[video]^" ^
  -map [video]:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

`-i` tells FFmpeg to use the following input as the source of stream(s) for the next operations.

`input.mp3` is the input file with a sound.

`inputX.jpg` are the input files with an images.

`-loop` tells FFmpeg to loop the next input image.

`-filter_complex` tells FFmpeg to use the following filters.

`trim` is the type of filter to set the duration of specific image, it can be used with `duration` option or with `start` and `end` options (this is where you need to paste values of your starting points).

`concat` is the type of filter to merge two previous parts of video into one part that can be used for the next `concat` operation.

`-map` tells FFmpeg what streams (video and audio) should be used to create the output file.

`-c` tells FFmpeg what codecs should be used to encode video and audio to create the output file.

`-shortest` tells the FFmpeg to use the shortest input stream as the duration of the output (in this case it is the input file with a sound as all images are in infinite loops).

`^` is Windows batch specific character used to be able to split one long command to a several lines of code. You can delete all `^` and use one long command instead:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp3 -loop 1 -i input1.jpg -loop 1 -i input2.jpg -loop 1 -i input3.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]trim=duration=0.3251[a]; [2:v]trim=start=0.3251:end=6.5712,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; [a][b]concat[c]; [3:v]trim=start=6.5712,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; [c][d]concat[video]" -map [video]:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

**How to add the next image?**

You need to add one more image as the input and change last few lines in the current set of filters:

```
   [a][b]concat[c]; ^
   [3:v]trim=start=6.5712,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; ^
   [c][d]concat[video]^" ^
```

with:

```
   [a][b]concat[c]; ^
   [3:v]trim=start=6.5712:end=12.8174,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; ^
   [c][d]concat[e]; ^
   [4:v]trim=start=12.8174,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[f]; ^
   [e][f]concat[video]^" ^
```

The letters `[a]`, `[b]`, `[c]` are the names of the variables - you can use any combination of letters here, not just one letter. For example: `[aa][ab]concat[ac]` would also work and `[video]` is a also a variable name used in this command.

Comment: Thank you! It works, if I would want to add more pictures then, I can add -i input4.jpg and in filter_complex i would repeat all that? Also what does that [a], [b], [c] mean in the filter_complex, what if I would use every single character from the alphabet

Comment: @dopuu I've answered your questions by editing my answer.